# Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'doctor1.education' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `education` where `education`.`dr_id` in (1))

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'doctor1.education' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `education` where `education`.`dr_id` in (1))

*here i want to use hasMany for my foreign key in table educations,here doctor id is foreign key*

**Doctor Model Code for doctors table:-**

```
public function educations(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Education','dr_id');
    }
```

**Education model for educations table:-**

```
public function doctor(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Doctor','dr_id');
    }
```

**Controller Code for this page:-**

```
public function profilesetting(){
        $userinfo = Doctor::with('educations')->where('id','=',session('drid'))->get();
        dd($userinfo);
    }
```

please tell me that how i solve this error?

Comment: Apparently the table `education` doesn't exist in the database `doctor1`. You might want to double-check what exists in. your database.

Comment: in database table name is educations, so my model name is Education

Comment: @ITS_HJ24 what is the table name in the database?

Comment: educations is the table name so i declare model name as Education

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**in database model cant find table educations i think use this line in Education model**

```
protected $table = "educations";
```